# How can I shrink and make a better use of this method? - RUBY (raw)

Tags: ruby, methods

[Working on a project and trying to turn this method (I Have some more similar methods like that in my project) into a more dynamic and concise way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22W5X.png)

**Data from image**

```
def proficiency_parser(stored_data, name, race, year, title, percentage)
  if stored_data.has_key?(name)
    if stored_data[name].has_key?(race)
      if stored_data[name][race].has_key?(year)
        stored_data[name][race][year][title] = percentage
      else
        stored_data[name][race][year] = {title => percentage}
      end
    else
      stored_data[name][race] = {year => {title => percentage}}
    end
  else
    stored_data[name] = {race => {year => {title => percentage}}}
  end
end
```

so essentially this method through my data to identify whether it meets so of those specification showing in the code, essentially I just don't want to use this amount of "elses" and "Ifs" if at all possible.

**Data**

```
stored_data
# => {"COLORADO"=>{3=>{2008=>{:math=>0.697}}}}
name
# => "COLORADO"
race
# => 3
year
# => 2008
title
# => :math
percentage
# => 0.697
```

Comment: Can you include some description of what this method is supposed to do, and what you mean by "make better use of"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" with its linked pages. Please don't use a link to an image (or to another site) for information that is essential to your question; Links rot then break, making your question worthless to those in the future searching for similar solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`Hash#dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) which is included in Ruby versions `2.3.0` or newer.

To summarize:

```
hash_1 = { a: { a: { a: "b" } } }
hash_2 = { c: { c: { c: "d" } } }
hash_1.dig(:a, :a, :a) # returns "b"
hash_2.dig(:a, :a, :a) # returns nil
```

So you could say `if hash_1.dig(:a, :a)` instead of

```
if hash_1[:a]
  if hash_1[:a][:a]
    # etc
```

There's also another way to do it, which is to rescue your `NoMethod []` errors.

Here's an example of that:

```
if hash_1[:a][:a][:a] rescue false
   puts "the key exists"
else
   puts "the key doesnt exist"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some recursive call

**Input data**

```
stored_data = {}
name = 'COLORADO'
race = 3
year = 2008
title = :math
percentage = 0.697
```

**Methods**

```
def proficiency_parser(stored_data, name, race, year, title, percentage)
  parser(stored_data, name, {race => {year => {title => percentage}}})
end

def parser(data, key, value)
  data[key] ? value.each { |k, v| parser(data[key], k, v) } : data[key] = value
end
```

**call**

```
proficiency_parser(stored_data, name, race, year, title, percentage)

p stored_data
# => {"COLORADO"=>{3=>{2008=>{:math=>0.697}}}}
```

I hope this helps